# how to print a given randomly generated letters into the form of a matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

```
import random
string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
for x in range(16):
    a = print(random.choice(string))
```

How to print these randomly generated letters in the form of a 4*4 matrix in python ?

Comment: nice task - what did you try to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ensure that there are no repeats of the letters, you can shuffle the letters, and pop from a list:

```
import random
letters = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
random.shuffle(letters)
for row in range(4):
    for col in range(4):
        print(letters.pop(), end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print 4 letters in 4 lines like this:

```
import random

string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
for x in range(4):
    print(''.join([random.choice(string) for _ in range(4)]))
```

**Output**

```
YTPB
CHQF
UNLC
BOMS
```

You can also represent a matrix as a list of list:

```
import random

string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
matrix = [[random.choice(string) for _ in range(4)] for _ in range(4)]
print(matrix)
```

**Output**

```
[['U', 'Z', 'L', 'L'], ['R', 'G', 'O', 'M'], ['W', 'X', 'U', 'I'], ['C', 'Q', 'O', 'W']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
matrix = np.random.choice(list(string),replace=False,size=(4,4))
print(matrix)
```

With `replace=False` to have no repetitions, `replace=True` to have potential repetitions.

You can reduce to three lines if you print the output of np.random.choice without assigning it to a variable name first.

You can also reduce to two lines, at the cost of readability, like this:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.random.choice(list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"),replace=False,size=(4,4)))
```